# Does Mono support System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Printing?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, printing, mono

I'm attempting to use Mono to load a bitmap and print it on Linux but I'm getting an exception.  Does Mono support printing on Linux?  The code/exception are below:

**EDIT:** No longer getting the exception, but I'm still curious what kind of support there is.  Leaving the code for posterity or something.

```
private void btnPrintTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _printDocTest.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    _printDocTest.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(50,50,50,50);
    _printDocTest.Print();
}

void _printDocTest_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  var bmp = new Bitmap("test.bmp");

  // Determine center of graph
  var xCenter = e.MarginBounds.X + (e.MarginBounds.Width - bmp.Width) / 2;
  var yCenter = e.MarginBounds.Y + (e.MarginBounds.Height - bmp.Height) / 2;

  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, xCenter, yCenter);

  e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: Oh..oops, looks like I was just specifying the file path wrong (changed it to open the file first then load it into a bitmap). Got it working now -- nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Mono docs](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General), I think yes:

> Managed.Windows.Forms (aka
>   System.Windows.Forms): A complete and
>   cross platform, System.Drawing based
>   Winforms implementation.

It also useful if you run the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/Moma) first.

Answer (score 5):

[According to](http://www.go-mono.com/archive/1.2/)

System.Drawing is now complete, and in addition to being the underlying rendering engine for Windows.Forms, it has also been tested for using third party controls that heavily depend on it.