# Printing from mono on OS X

Tags: macos, printing, mono

I am pretty new to the platform, but I would like to know if anybody tried printing from a Mac using the Mono framework?

Seems like the internal namespaces that are usually used to print on other platforms are not fully implemented (System.Drawing, System.Drawing.Printing) so does anybody know of a better way to do printing? Or is MonoMac required to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Mono support System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455/does-mono-support-system-drawing-and-system-drawing-printing)

Comment: I don't think this is really a dup. The answers may overlap, but the actual question is different.

Comment: I don't think the question is a dup at all. System.Drawing.Printing works on Linux, but I am asking about OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if System.Drawing.Printing works on OS X, but the GtkPrint API in gtk-sharp does.

Comment: Last I tried, it could print to PDF, but not directly to a printer. Of course, printing the PDF is trivial.