# Printing PS/PDF files from Mono

Tags: printing, mono

I am porting a C# program to Linux (using Mono).  The only compatibility issues that [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) has found were all related to printing: P/Invokes of functions from winspool.drv:

- ClosePrinter
- EndDocPrinter
- EndPagePrinter
- OpenPrinter
- StartDocPrinter
- StartPagePrinter
- WritePrinter

These are all used in the same class, which prints files (which must be either PDF or PS) by wrapping them in [PJL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Job_Language) (to set the paper size/tray/orientation) and calling [WritePrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'll need to rewrite this printing logic with non-Windows-specific code.  [A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455/does-mono-support-system-drawing-and-system-drawing-printing) refers to [System.Drawing.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.aspx), but it seems to be way too low level.  I don't want `DrawString` and `DrawImage`, I want "print this PostScript file".  Is there functionality in Mono to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to call the [`lp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp) command.